# Press button (<input type="button"> BUT NOT <input type="submit">) and send a form but don't leave current page

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to send a form on button press (`<input type="button">` BUT NOT `<input type="submit">`) without leaving current page and don't refresh it and show message on success, such as "Your form has been successfully sent!"? I guess that I need to use jQuery for that....isn't it?

I'm using this code for example:

```
<form name="myform" action="SendForm.jsp" method="post">
   Username: <input type="text" name="user">
   <input type="button" id="b1" value="Send">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use ajax for form submission

Comment: Use AJAX and on success show the message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a page refresh, you're going to need [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

DEMO in jQuery

```
<form name="myform" action="SendForm.jsp" method="post" id="myForm">
   Username: <input type="text" name="user">
   <input type="button" id="b1" value="Send">
</form>

$("#b1").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'SendForm.jsp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function(){
            alert("Your form has been successfully sent!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just one problem with this: his button doesn't submit the form. The type is wrong. Change it to a submit and it will work

Comment: You see this form will be sent only if <input type="submit"> will be pressed but I need it on button pressed <input type="button">

Comment: @DenissMuntjans change for meeting your needs

Comment: I'm trying to make it work but it doesn't! I don't know why when I press a button nothing happens :( Please could you help me! So I inserted jQuery code inside <script type="text/javascript"> in the <head> and HTML code inside <body>...is there anything else I need to include to make it work??? Thanks!

Comment: @DenissMuntjans you need to put the js code before the close `body` tag, aka `</body>` or wrap them into `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Thanks, but it only shows me the message but don't really send a form and I double check the name of the form I sent but still nothing :(

Comment: @DenissMuntjans do you run your web server to make your .jsp file actually work? I mean like a Tomcat or something

Comment: Yes I use a Tomcat for that and it should print a string in console if form has been sent, actually that form takes a parameter and print it in console but its only show this message ("Your form has been successfully sent!") and doesn't print the string form me :(

Comment: @DenissMuntjans if your .jsp file print something to console, you should check it in your editor(eg. Eclipse or sth) not in browser, btw, you should make sure your .jsp file is in the same folder as your html file

Comment: I check it in Eclipse, I know that and these files are all in the same directory nut still nothing...thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to work with a button type. In your Send button you would add an onclick event

```
<input type="button" id="b1" value="Send" onclick="myfunction();">
```

Then you would write a JS function that uses AJAX to send your data

```
function myfunction() {
    jQuery.ajax({url: 'my/url/here'}).done(function () { /*do something here*/ });
}
```